# Is it alright for multiple people running .net app that is stored under same network directory?

Tags: .net, vb.net

There is a .Net executable (with a group of DLL's etc) that up to 100 people will be using simulatiously during the course of the day.  Is it still acceptable/good practice to have all the users just have a shortcut to the network path for this executable?  Or would it be better to copy the .exe, .dll's, etc locally to each users machine?  What are the pros/cons of each and is there a standard way of doing this type of thing?

Comment: You should really give them their own copy if this is a client app. That's the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having multiple people running the same application via a network share isn't a great idea. Of course, deploying a stand-alone application to 100 users is a maintenance nightmare. Imagine that you need to deploy a new feature. You (or some other poor sucker) is going to have to go around to each PC and update it.

I'd recommend making a [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) installer for the application. That way, you could provide your end-users with a link to the installer, and the application can automatically update itself as necessary.

Comment: That makes sense.  I guess I'm also trying to understand what happens behind the scenes when multiple people are accessing/running the same .exe/dll's.  Is it somehow running from multiple copies for each person?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with DBM, [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is the best practice for this situation.

When running off of a network drive directly, you can run into security issues, as the .Net run-time will automatically not fully trust an executable that is loaded from a network location. Also, (this was before .Net but i think the same thing applies), we used to have a .exe file out on a network share and we had to ask everyone to exit the program before it would allow you to update the file. This is a big pain when publishing updates.